# Get all uniq combinations of values with respect to groups

Tags: javascript, typescript, combinations, permutation, ramda.js

I have a set of attribute values:

Example:

```
[
  {
    memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
    value: '1'  
  },
  {
    memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
    value: '2'  
  },
  {
    memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
    value: '1'  
  },
  {
    memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
    value: '2'  
  }
]
```

Now I want to get all the unique combinations for given member attributes.

So if I wanted unique combinations for member attributes 'a' and 'b' the result would be:

```
[
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
     value: '1'  
   },
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
     value: '1'  
   }
],
[
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
     value: '1'  
   },
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
     value: '2'  
   }
],
[
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
     value: '2'  
   },
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
     value: '1'  
   }
],
[
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'a' },
     value: '2'  
   },
   {
     memberAttribute: { attributeName: 'b' },
     value: '2'  
   }
]
```

I need to be able to give n number of input member attributes but can only achieve the desired result for 2 input attributes.

Current horrible solution:

```
export const getAttributeCombinations = (
  attributes: MemberAttributeValue[]
) => {
  // TODO - This algorithm only supports 2 attribute types
  // It should support any number of attribute types

  const combinations = new Array<Array<MemberAttributeValue>>();

  for (const attribute of attributes) {
    let unusedAttributes = allExcept(attribute, attributes);

    const permutate = () => {
      const combination = [attribute];
      const toRemove = new Array<Number>();

      for (let i = 0; i < unusedAttributes.length; i++) {
        const unusedAttribute = unusedAttributes[i];

        if (!attributeTypeAlreadyExists(unusedAttribute, combination)) {
          toRemove.push(i);
          combination.push(unusedAttribute);
        }
      }

      for (const index of toRemove) {
        unusedAttributes = remove(index, 1, unusedAttributes);
      }

      combinations.push(combination);
    };

    permutate();

    while (unusedAttributes.length > 0) {
      permutate();
    }
  }

  const sortedCombinations = map(sortByAttributeName, combinations);
  return uniqByCombination(sortedCombinations);
};
```

Example of a failing jest test:

```
it('given 3 attribute types should return 12 combinations', () => {
    const inclusionAttributes: MemberAttributeValue[] = [
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'gender',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: 'Male'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'gender',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: 'Female'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'age band',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: '0-50'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'age band',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: '51+'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'likes',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: 'cats'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'likes',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: 'dogs'
      },
      {
        memberAttribute: {
          attributeName: 'likes',
          aliases: [],
          contentType: ContentType.String,
          type: AttributeType.Mandatory
        },
        value: 'goats'
      }
    ];

    const combinations = getAttributeCombinations(inclusionAttributes);

    expect(combinations.length).toBe(12);

    for (const combination of combinations) {
      expect(combination.length).toBe(3);
    }
  });
```

Comment: The current solution works but only for 2 attributes groups. I need to be able to support n input attributes to group b. So there might be member attribute c and d each with x number of unique values. You should be able to group by a, b, c and d.

Comment: @lukejkw can you give a example object (input object) for 3 or 4 attribute group?

Comment: It would look very similar to the example given but with different attribute name. Do you want me to update the question? It's also important to note that one attribute type could have many values. So 'a' could have many different values. @KoushikChatterjee

Comment: hmm, don't change that and update the question by adding another example input for 3 attributes if possible

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee I have added the failing jest test for 3 attributes

Comment: but what is `ContectType` and `AttributeType` here?

Comment: and combination length should be 16, not 12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161298/discussion-between-lukejkw-and-koushik-chatterjee).

Comment: @lukejkw sure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be relatively simple in Ramda except that Ramda's `xprod` function works only on two lists.  If it worked on a list of lists, we could do this in just a few steps.  But it's easy enough to write our own:

```
const xproduct = reduce(pipe(xprod, map(unnest)), [[]])

const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(path(['memberAttribute', 'attributeName'])),
  values,
  xproduct
)

const inclusionAttributes = [
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "gender"}, "value": "Male"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "gender"}, "value": "Female"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "age band"}, "value": "0-50"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "age band"}, "value": "51+"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "likes"}, "value": "cats"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "likes"}, "value": "dogs"}, 
  {"memberAttribute": {"attributeName": "likes"}, "value": "goats"}
]

console.log(transform(inclusionAttributes))
//=> Male/0-50/cats, Male/0-50/dogs, Male/0-50/goats, Male/51+/cats,...
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20xproduct%20%3D%20reduce%28pipe%28xprod%2C%20map%28unnest%29%29%2C%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28path%28%5B%27memberAttribute%27%2C%20%27attributeName%27%5D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20xproduct%0A%29%0Aconst%20inclusionAttributes%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22gender%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%22Male%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22gender%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%22Female%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22age%20band%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%220-50%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22age%20band%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%2251%2B%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22likes%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%22cats%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22likes%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%22dogs%22%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7B%22memberAttribute%22%3A%20%7B%22attributeName%22%3A%20%22likes%22%7D%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%22goats%22%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Atransform%28inclusionAttributes%29)**.

Comment: Incredible answer. Knew that there was a simple elegant way to do this i ramda.